# How to return List of QuerySets in graphql query as separate list elements?

Tags: django, graphql, graphene-python, graphene-django

The problem I am facing is that I have `custom_filter` of `MyModel` which return the list of `<QuerySet>` like

```
[<QuerySet [<MyModel: xyz>]>, <QuerySet [<MyModel: xyz>, <MyModel: xyz>,<MyModel: xyz>]>]
```

**The object type**

```py
class MyModelNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model=MyModel
        filter_fields=['id]
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
```

**Query**

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
   my_model_items = graphene.List(MyModelNode)

   def resolve_my_model_items(self, info, **kwargs):
      my_model_filtered_items = MyModel.objects.custom_filter(kwargs)
      # my_model_filtered_items holds the list of querysets
      return my_model_filtered_items
```

How to handle list of querysets.
The graphql respone of the query should give a list which have the querysets as elements.

```
[
  {
  //These are from first <QuerySet>
  "myModelItems":[
      {
        "fieldsIaskedFor":"response"
      }
    ]

  },


  {
  //These are from second <QuerySet>
  "myModelItems":[
      {
        "fieldsIaskedFor":"resp"
      },
      {
        "fieldsIaskedFor":"resp"
      },
      {
        "fieldsIaskedFor":"resp"
      },
    ]

  },


]
```

How to get results of different querysets in separate list elements ?
The number of `<QuerySet>` are  not fixed.

**What I have to do to achieve that ?.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating two object types and simply nesting one inside other.

The first object type will be the `DjangoObjectType` of `MyModel`

```py
class DjangoMyModelNode(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        filter_fields = ['id']
        interfaces = (graphene.relay.Node,)
```

The second objects type will be a custom `ObjectType`

```py
class MyModelNode(graphene.ObjectType):
    my_model_items = graphene.List(DjangoMyModelNode)

    def resolve_my_model_items(self, info, **kwargs):
        return self
```

The query will remain the same

```py
class Query(graphene.ObjectType):
    my_model_items = graphene.List(MyModelNode)

    def resolve_my_model_items(self, info, **kwargs):
        my_model_filtered_items = MyModel.objects.custom_filter(kwargs)
        # my_model_filtered_items holds the list of querysets
        return my_model_filtered_items
```

**This will return things according to desired result**